# How to replace require in ES Module ~ const ioSoc = require("./utilities/socket.js").init(server);

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I saw this line of code when using websockets. How can I replace require in ES Module ~ const ioSoc = require("./utilities/socket.js").init(server)when my node server is using ES modules / Import.

```
const clients = {};
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("Connected to database");
    const server = app.listen(PORT);
    const ioSoc = require("./utilities/socket.js").init(server);
    ioSoc.on("connection", (socket) => {
      socket.on("add-user", (data) => {
        clients[data.agent_id] = {
          socket: socket.id,
        };
      });

      //removing the socket on disconnect
      socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        for (const agent_id in clients) {
          if (clients[agent_id].socket === socket.id) {
            delete clients[agent_id];
            break;
          }
        }
      });
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question but you can try something like:
import * as ioSoc from '{path}'

Comment: The better question should have been, how can I create a utility to initialize & get io because it's the one am trying to import as ioSoc and this is how it looks below;
```
let io;

module.exports = {
  init: (httpServer) => {
    io = require("socket.io")(httpServer);
    return io;
  },
  getIO: () => {
    if (!io) {
      throw new Error("socket.io is not initialized!");
    }
    return io;
  },
};
```